# How to preserve closed captions in ffmpeg transcoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to preserve closed caption in ffmpeg transcoding.
Any one have idea about how to preserve captions in ffmepg?

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input`

Comment: Thanks for reply @llogan , Currently captions preserve by ffmpeg is only if decoder and encoder is same.You can say ffmepg only bypass or copy captions.

Comment: I have found something that ffmpeg is not support captioning in case of transcoding , without transcoding it is working as ffmpeg only copy captions.If we try to decode h264 and encode in mpeg2 or vice versa than ffmpeg fail to preserve captions.If we do h264 decoding and mpeg2 encoding or vice versa it will work.Caption extraction not supported by ffmpeg Thanks @llogan.